# getID3 get mp3 length unexspected T_ECHO

Tags: php, mp3, id3, getid3

i want to get the length of a MP3-File in PHP. The code i´ve found by google is from getID3, but it dosen't works.

I always get the following errormessage and i´dont know how i can fix it.

`PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /.../getDuration.php on line 17`

My PHP-Code:

```
<?php

$include = dirname(__FILE__). '/';

include_once $include . 'getid3.php';
include_once $include . 'getid3.lib.php';
include_once $include . 'module.audio.mp3.php';
include_once $include . 'module.tag.apetag.php';
include_once $include . 'module.tag.id3v1.php';
include_once $include . 'module.tag.id3v2.php';


$pathName = '/var/..../audio/audio.mp3';

$getID3 = new getID3;
$ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($pathName)
echo $ThisFileInfo['playtime_string'];

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a semicolon at the end of this line

```
$ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($pathName);
                                         //^------ Add one here
```

Comment: But know i get the message undefined index: playtime_string you maybe know why?

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($ThisFileInfo);` instead of `echo` ?

Comment: Ah now it´s work. The var_dump was a good idea it tells me this. `"Caught exception: Required module.tag.lyrics3.php is missing.` After  including the php-file all is fine. Tank You very much. :-)

Comment: @SnowN, Always do a `var_dump` when you are stuck .. also enable the error reporting always.. `<?php error_reporting(-1);` on top. Glad you got it working.